# Python: a part of my program is looping over and over again instead of continuing onwards

Tags: python, calculator

I'm new to programming so sorry if I sound like I don't know what I'm talking about. I wanted to create an advanced calculator, one that could calculate squares and even specific equations such as Pythagoras and square root, after doing a bit of research and understand how to actually calculate these on computer, I found myself stuck with making a normal sum:

```
number1add = int(input("What is your First number:"))
number2add = int(input("What is you Second number:"))
sum = number1add + number2add

if intro == "sum":
    print(number1add, number2add)
    print(sum)
```

You see for some reason, when I run this, the program keeps on repeating on the "What is your First Number", "What is your second number", instead of moving on, I understand this could probably be fixed by just adding a statement that transitions the two, but after searching on the internet for a while, no post resembled the issue I seem to be getting, if anyone knows the answer, I would love to know

Edit: Since a lot of people seem to be getting confused, here is the full code

```
intro = str(input("What calculation do you want to perform:"))

number1add = int(input("What is your First number:"))
number2add = int(input("What is you Second number:"))
sum = number1add + number2add

print(intro)

if intro == 'sum':
    print(number1add, number2add)
    print(sum)
```

And here is what happens when I execute the code:

```
What calculation do you want to perform:sum
What is your First number:2
What is you Second number:2
What is your First number:2
What is you Second number:2
What is your First number:
```

Comment: There isn't a single loop in the code you've shown here, please make a [mcve]

Comment: Please show your entire code. The way your code is now, it should ask for two numbers, and then the script would end.

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Post [mre]. Also don't use `sum` as name, it's built-in function.

Comment: Apart from "intro = str(input("What calculation do you want to perform:"))" being a part of the code, that is the exact code that was used when the issue occurred

Comment: The posted code does not produce the problem you claim.

Comment: The code posted [runs fine](https://ideone.com/89qZO3) - Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Well it did for me, unfortunately I don't know if I can send screenshots through here to show you, but I'll try my best, this is what the terminal looks like when I'm going through the program:

What calculation do you want to perform:sum
What is your First number:2
What is you Second number:2
What is your First number:2
What is you Second number:2
What is your First number:

Comment: I understand the spacing and indexing isn't perfect because it won't let me go down the line, but hopefully you get a rough idea

Comment: how do you call the python program from terminal?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't seem to understand the question?

Comment: @ClayWolf, how are you running the code to get this issue? Are you running it in VS Code or Jupyter Notebooks or something else? Or are you calling python from your command prompt / terminal / powershell? Did you save a .py file that you are running?

Answer (score 0):

Right, I somehow fixed the issue, I just formated the code differently and all of a sudden it worked, I really I could say why this happened but tbh I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
intro = input("What calculation do you want to perform:")

number1add = input("What is your First number:")
number2add = input("What is you Second number:")
sum1 = int(number1add) + int(number2add)

print(intro)

if (intro == 'sum'):
    print(number1add, number2add)
    print(sum1)
```

Also you had given integer name as `sum` which is a built-in function in python.

Answer (score -2):

I can see that you're using "intro" but you're not defining it anyway, so the loop "if" won't start and will run from the top of the program again, or will just finish running

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.  When you accumulate enough reputation, you will gain the commenting privilege.  Until then, you'll just have to listen to the comment stream, answer when you can, and use the review queues to get points.

Comment: If you look at the comments, I just forgot to mention it, but I did define in fact: intro = str(input("What calculation do you want to perform:")). And right after I put: print(intro)

Comment: Yes, now I see that part, maybe you should post the entire code to see why this loop doesn't end, because the logic in the code is correct, the conditions and the chose for an operation.